# Dynamically creating form inputs in react based on configurations stored in DB

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a `dynamic forms` in React.

The `form` should be fully dynamic means say if my API returns the JSON object having different labels for form fields and their types like text, textarea or a dropdown.
So whatever type of form API returns that form field should be displayed in a form.
I am unable to implement it in `reactjs`.

Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, you wish to generate a Form from a Json. If so then you can either write a simple algorithm yourself or install a library that does it for you, There are many of those. A simple first result on google googling `reactjs generate form from json` returned this https://sairamkrish.medium.com/rapid-development-of-data-collection-platform-with-reactjs-and-json-schema-ef147f4c665 it has some library suggestions. Additionally, not related to a problem, would recommend using ant design. Will greatly increase productivity and form validations are quick to setup.

Comment: In the simplest words: you should use a `map` function over your json to map it to a JSX form.